# How to upgrade the docx format to the latest by docx？

Tags: python, format, upgrade, docx, template-strings

**The original file is docx format**, which **has multiple tables**, but there **may be format problems**, so it **cannot be read by python-docx**.

### **✔️ 1.Solution by hand:**

**solve** the question  **by click  [save as ....] menu**. A prompt box appears:

[prompt box : appears upgrade to newest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Tau.png)

### ❓2. Question:

How to **implement [save as] function through Python-docx**, **upgrade the docx format to the latest**?

*Thanks for any suggestion！*

### **3. appendix**

```
from docx import Document
from win32com import client as wc

file = 'D:\\1.docx'
word = wc.Dispatch("Word.Application") 
word.Visible = False

doc = word.Documents.Open(file) 
doc.SaveAs("{}".format(file), 12)
doc.Close() 

word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

With a compromise method,

1. we first created a blank DOCX,
2. then using Win32 libraries to copy the content as a whole to the blank DOCX,
3. testing available

Still looking forward to optimization methods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).